# Difference between UK honors and pass degree from Indian degrees

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, united-kingdom

I am from India and we have two different degrees. One would be honors and other would be pass. I graduated with a Bsc(pass) degree. Now this degree included studying Physics, Mathematics and Computer Sciences at breadth. An honors degree would require me to complete a depth requirement in only one subject.

Now as I was looking for the eligibility for a masters' degree, I am finding it difficult to find the equivalent of my degree in UK.

Comment: Why was this question down voted? Please leave a comment when you down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All UK universities use a Government body to verify and calibrate overseas qualifications for the purposes of admissions and employment etc.

Their web site is [www.naric.org.uk](http://www.naric.org.uk/).

It is their rating of your qualifications against an equivalent UK degree that will be used by any admissions tutor of any Master's course you applied for.

I quote from NARIC:

> UK NARIC can provide two officially-recognised documents. The first is a Statement of Comparability, which will include information about the standards of your awards in comparison to UK qualifications.  It confirms the status of overseas qualifications and their comparable level in the UK, irrespective of it being an academic, vocational or professional award. It is used by universities, colleges, employers and Government departments and agencies, forming part of their decision-making process.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to vary from university to university and course to course. A good starting place might be the [international qualifications required for Cambridge](http://www.graduate.study.cam.ac.uk/international-students/international-qualifications) and [the University of Warwick](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/study/international/admissions/entry-requirements/#i).