# About eligibility for the Cambridge International Scholarship Scheme

Tags: university, united-kingdom

On the website of the University of Cambridge, they state the eligibility criteria for the [Cambridge international scholarship scheme (CISS)](http://www.cambridgestudents.cam.ac.uk/fees-and-funding/funding/cambridge-international-scholarship-scheme-ciss-graduate). One of them is:

"Have a high upper-second-class undergraduate honours degree from a UK Higher Education Institution, or an equivalent from an Overseas Institution".

I don't understand it. Can someone explain to me what is precisely meant by that?

Comment: I had a similar question regarding equivalent Indian degree. (Still has no answers): http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45115/difference-between-uk-honors-and-pass-degree-from-indian-degrees

Comment: You can find a relevant answer here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10227/what-does-first-class-or-2-1-honours-degree-mean/10231#10231

Answer (score 2):

Given that that's the same as the [requirement for applying to Cambridge](http://www.graduate.study.cam.ac.uk/courses/entry-requirements/academic-requirements), have a look at the [international qualifications page](http://www.graduate.study.cam.ac.uk/international-students/international-qualifications) to see how degrees in your country map to Cambridge degrees.

Comment: I believe that the "University Minimum Requirement" in that will correspond to the "upper-second-class undergraduate honours degree" in the CISS requirements.